# How to merge select files in branch with master in Git?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

As I'm learning Git/GitHub, I've got a master branch that looks like this:

```
file1.py
file2.py
file3.py
file4.py
config.json # generic settings
```

I also have a branch for test running on a local system that looks like this:

```
file1.py
file2.py
file3.py
file4.py
config.json # settings configured for my local tests
```

I do the work on the test run branch.  I want to merge everything for `file[1-4].py` into master each time, but not `config.json`.

What is the correct way to structure this workflow on a single-person repo?  Am I already breaking good Git practice?  Do I just add `config.json` to `.gitignore` on the test runner branch?

I'm using VS Code for this, so if there's a VS Code workflow to accomplish this, that would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
git add file*
```

and commit changes on the test branch.

```
git switch master
```

to switch to  master branch, and

```
git merge test
```

to merge test branch into master